# How to load a html file into jquery tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Using jquery load seems easy enough when used to load the file into a div like so

```
$('#div1').load('ajax/test.html');
```

But I have divs that I created into tabs. I have something like

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">one</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">two</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
this is tab 1
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
this is tab 2
</div>
</div>
```

and my js looks like

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
$("#tabs").tabs();
    $('#tabs-1').load('testing.html');
});
```

However nothing displays in tab-1 and I've searched and haven't found anything on loading tabs with html file
Edit:
Image of the directory structure:
!(http://s11.postimg.org/hwj34tlir/snapshot1.png)

testing.html is the content i want to load into the tab. 
projectscript is my javascript file
htmlPageWithTabs is my html page

I changed the path to
../files/testing.html and it still doesn't seem to work. what am i missing?

Comment: try the same path  "ajax/test.html"

Comment: @user instead of tabs?

Comment: @rps it still doesn't work

Comment: If you do something simpler like `$('#tabs-1').html('testing')` does it work?

Comment: I think, its not getting the right path. check the console for errors.

Comment: can you post the folder structure. It must be path issue.

Comment: @khan i just did. Im starting to have the feeling that it is a path issue. at least i hope so

Comment: did you try `files/testing.html` as path?

Comment: yes. i tried that and ../files/testing.html

Comment: do you see any error in console(press ctrl+shift+j in browser)

Comment: what is inside testing.html? probably something which is stopping it to getting loaded?

Comment: i can't imagine what. it has what i posted...the divs and tabs stuff

Comment: you mean, your div and tabs you posted are in the file you are going to load?

Comment: opps sorry my mistake. testing has 3 divs, each div contains a header and a list of questions

Comment: ...no. why would it work now? i didnt change anything

Comment: @khan thanks a lot for your help. i figured it out. there was an issue w my web server. so...nothing is wrong with the code :)

Answer (score 2):

Can you give more information about the actual path of the files you want to load ?

I think there are 2 options :

- you're trying to load a content from an external URL which won't work because of the  [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)
- you're trying to load a file from your server but you're not calling the right path (missing "/" at the begining)

Comment: i just looked a screen shot of the dorectory structure. i think you may be right.

Comment: Glad I can help. Feel free to validate my answer if it made it work. If you still have trouble, ask ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following callback to see what the error is.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tabs").tabs();

  $("#tabs-1").load("testing.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
    if (status == "error") {
      alert(xhr.status + " " + xhr.statusText);
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div id="tabs">
<ul>
<li><a href="#tabs-1">one</a></li>
<li><a href="#tabs-2">two</a></li>
</ul>
<div id="tabs-1">
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe> 
</div>
<div id="tabs-2">
<iframe src="http://www.youtube.com"></iframe> 
</div>
</div>
```

without javascript.

let me know something

Comment: It would seem like the whole point here is to load dynamically with ajax.

Comment: yes, russel is right. I don't think iframe would serve my purposes

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#tabs-1').append("<div id='content1'></div>");
$('#tabs-1').find('#content1').load("test.html");
```